# Python regex: How to substitute and return matches in one pass?

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace all matches in a string, and also get an array of the matches.

Here's how to do it with two functions:

```
str = "foo123bar456"
nums = re.findall(r'\d+', str)
str = re.sub(r'\d+', '', str)
```

But this goes through the string twice unnecessarily. How can I do this in one pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `re.sub` the argument `repl` can be a function that returns a string. We can use this to add the matches to a list:

```
import re


def substitute(string):
    def _sub(match):
        matches.append(match)
        return ''

    matches = []
    new_string = re.sub(r'\d+', _sub, string)
    return new_string, matches


print(substitute('foo123bar456'))
> ('foobar', [<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 6), match='123'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 12), match='456'>])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a lambda function in `re.sub`:

```
>>> str = "foo123bar456"
>>> arr=[]
>>> print re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m: arr.append(m.group(1)), str)
foobar
>>> print arr
['123', '456']
```